# Responsive footer always in bottom

Tags: css

I'm having trouble by creating a responsive footer that always stay on the bottom of the page. The code I'm actually using is this:

```
body
{
    margin: 0 0 200px; //Same height of the footer
}
footer
{
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 200px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
    background-color: rgba(67, 191, 115, 0.95);
}
```

I use:

```
<div class='main-content'>
//Content
</div>
<footer>
//Footer content
</footer>
```

Well, the problem is if I resize the screen and the content is larger than the resolution the footer lets a white space, like this:
[image]

I am trying to solve this problem. If I use `position: fixed` the problem disappears, but I don't want the footer following the scroll. I think the problem is in the 100 percent width. The footer of this site, Stack Overflow, works as I need. If I resize the window the footer remains the same, no white space. How to achieve this? How to make the footer cover all the width without let white space even if the resolution is lower than the page like occurs here, in Stack Overflow?

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: By "always at the bottom" do you mean the bottom of the window of the bottom of the page? Absolute will move relative to page size(always on the same spot on the page) while fixed is the same place on the screen (removed from document flow) is that what you were having trouble with?

Comment: Also try adding this at the beginning of your css doc: `*{ margin:0; padding:0; } body,html{ width:100%; height:100%; }` may help.

Comment: @CalebB The problem is that I have a white space. I need the footer covering all the page with the content width.

Answer (score 0):

This [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ajayendra2707/0ng4fjm1/1/) I am creating based on your html.

This is work as responsive, I am not seen any issue as you tell.

I think may be the issue with `height:200px` , just remove and check.

Still you have issue , update the jsfiddle.

Comment: No, the issue remains. What I could tell is that the footer width is changing if I resize the page and lets that white space because the page content exceeds the resolution. I use as an example here footer of Stack Overflow. I can change the resolution of the page and the footer remains the same width without a change. That's what I need.

Answer (score 0):

You should indeed use fixed positioning. This is what we do in our apps, running on browsers and Android/iOS devices:

Of course, you are using HTML5 so this page will not work on older browsers (IE7, IE8).

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  /*
                       This height just to show that the footer stays at the
                       bottom of the page even when scrolling all the way down.
                    */
  height: 2000px;
}

footer {
  position: fixed;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: rgba(67, 191, 115, 0.95);
}
```

```html
<div class='main-content'>
  //Content
</div>
<footer>
  //Footer content
</footer>
```

Comment: A fixed position is not going to be responsive because it is fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I like flexbox. [CSS tricks - Guide to Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/)
Try this:

```css
main {
    height: 95vh;
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: column wrap;
    justify-content: space-around;
    align-items: center; }
header,
footer  { flex: 0 1 auto; }
article { flex: 10 1 auto; }
```

```html
<main>
    <header>Title Here</header>
    <article>Main Article</article>
    <footer>Copyright and Contact Me</footer>
</main>
```

Comment: Thanks, but the issue remains even using this method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Galen Gidman https://galengidman.com/2014/03/25/responsive-flexible-height-sticky-footers-in-css/ for this:

```
<header class="page-row">
    <h1>Site Title</h1>
</header>

<main class="page-row page-row-expanded">
    <p>Page content goes here.</p>
</main>

<footer class="page-row">
  <p>Copyright, blah blah blah.</p>
</footer>
```

And the CSS:

```
html,
body {height: 100%;}

body {display: table; width: 100%;}

.page-row {display: table-row; height: 1px;}

.page-row-expanded {height: 100%;}
```

Galan: The only real caveat to this solution that I’ve encountered so far is the styling limitations present with elements using display: table-row. Often padding, margin, etc. don’t behave as expected. This is easy enough to work around by adding a  or something inside the .page-row and styling that.